# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.content.res.Resources$Theme.rebase []

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, proguard

After I set `minifyEnabled true`, I got this error in my released app

Any idea how to solve it?

```
2020-07-01 11:51:33.651 30098-30098/? I/ResourcesCompat: Failed to retrieve rebase() method
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.content.res.Resources$Theme.rebase []
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2069)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$ThemeCompat$ImplApi23.rebase(SourceFile:3)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$ThemeCompat.rebase(SourceFile:3)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachBaseContext2(SourceFile:32)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:1)
        at com.kahkeshan.tv_app.base.BaseActivity.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:1)
        at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:7244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

settings in gradle file:

```
  release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: Hello Mona were you able to find the cause of this exception? I'm facing the same problem here.

Comment: Any solution for the issue? Currently facing the same issue.  when I click error from logcat  I redirect to below method of the activity.

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(localizationDelegate.attachBaseContext(newBase))
    }

Comment: Sorry, I solved this but I forgot to write the solution here. Unfortunately, I can't remember the solution now. Sorry again that I couldn't help you. @HiteshDhamshaniya

Comment: oh.. no :(, if you write the solution, it would help other developers who are stuck with this issue like me. Anyways Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your ProGuard configuration file, you will need to add a `-keep` rule for the missing method `rebase()`. The following `-keep` option will do the trick;

```
-keep class android.content.res.Resources$Theme {
  void rebase();
}
```

Using the [ProGuard Playground](https://playground.proguard.com/), you can see the effect of your `-keep` options in the class tree of your project. It can help you create fine-tuned `-keep` options to solve similar issues.